# drools integer type difference between quoted and not quoted

Tags: integer, drools, quotes

I have a Integer type bar in Foo class, I want to know is there any difference between quoted and not quoted in Drools rule? 
just as follows:

```
bar == 123
```

vs.

```
bar == "123"
```

by the way, I have made some tests, both work fine in syntax.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drools rules use MVEL language syntax. MVEL applies value type correction in cases where two incomparable types are compared. You can read more about this here: https://github.com/imona/tutorial/wiki/MVEL-Guide#value-coercion